# Autoplay (slideshow) a lightbox gallery in magnific lightbox?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, lightbox, magnific-popup

I've been looking for a responsive lightbox that will autoplay a gallery starting at a specified point in the gallery. [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) looks pretty solid. Anyone have a way for it to act as a lightbox slideshow - that is, have the gallery autoadvance?

Looks from the [Magnific documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) like there should be a way that makes use of `magnificPopup.next();`, `magnificPopup.updateItemHTML();` and/or callback events, but that's beyond my javascripting

thanks!

edit: if you're thinking "umm fancybox's autoPlay?," sure, that would work *also*. I'd still like to try out Magnific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put interval in `open` callback.

```
callbacks: {
    open: function() {
       setInterval(function() {
            $.magnificPopup.instance.next();
       }, 2000);
   }
}
```

Of course it's very basic implementation, but you may go as far as you need.

Comment: Looks good, not working. Typo I think, starting with closing `setInterval(`. Embarrassed to say I can't catch it no matter how much I fiddle. Thanks for the help Dmitry

Comment: @henry Yes it's missing the `function()` which I already added. The code above should work now. But another problem is that how to stop the slideshow when the next/prev button has been clicked?

Comment: Hello @JohnnyQ, did you find away to avoid the slideshow when the next/prev button has been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a bit of tinkering though there is a quirk. I have two instances of magnificPopup on the page. One called only on  elements and not in gallery mode and one with all items in an array and gallery enabled. This code is in the latter of the two. It, however, affects BOTH instances, and my 'non' gallery refreshes every 5 seconds! Regardless, the below code is what you're looking for:

```
callbacks: {
    open: setInterval( function() {
        $.magnificPopup.instance.next()
    }, 5000 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Magnific Popup slide show uses a small form with a "Start Slide Show" button and an input for the desired interval. The slide show object has basically the following code:

```
var slideshow = {
    interval: 4,
    intervalTimer: null,
    currImgNo: 0,
    insertController: function(parentElement) {
        // DOM code to create form html
        $(slideShowStartButton).on('click', function(e){
            $('.popup-parent-container').magnificPopup('open', slideshow.currImgNo);
            if ($.magnificPopup.instance.index + 1
                    < $.magnificPopup.instance.items.length) {
                $.magnificPopup.instance.next();
                slideshow.currImgNo++;
            } else {
                $('.popup-parent-container').magnificPopup('close');
            }
        }, slideshow.interval * 1000);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    slideshow.insertController(/* This code depends on the slide show controller html */);
});
```

The slide show property *currImgNo* is used to enter the slide show with the last popuped image and to prevent looping.

Magnific Popup got extra lines in the open and close event handlers:

```
$('.popup-parent-container').magnificPopup({
    // ...
    callbacks: {
        open: function() {
            slideshow.currImgNo = this.index;
        },
        close: function() {
            if (slideshow.intervalTimer) {
                clearInterval(slideshow.intervalTimer);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine, at least for some of WebKit and Gecko browsers that I tested.

My version additionally launches full screen mode, but that requires some more code to work across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my hat into the ring here. Here's what I ended up using for a slideshow. This will reset the slideshow timer whenever the image is loaded.

```
// .slidegroup is the specific class I'm using to define my slideshow.
if( $( '.slidegroup' ).length ) {
            
    let slideGroupTimer;
    
    $( '.slidegroup' ).magnificPopup( {
        type        : 'image',
        tLoading    : 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass   : 'mfp-img-mobile',
        preloader   : true,
        gallery: {
            enabled: true,
            navigateByImgClick: true,
            preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
        },
        callbacks: {
            imageLoadComplete: function() {
                slideGroupTimer = clearInterval( slideGroupTimer );
                ( function() {
                    if( 'undefined' === typeof slideGroupTimer ) {
                        slideGroupTimer = setInterval( function() {
                            $.magnificPopup.instance.next()
                        }, 8000 );
                    }
                } )();
            }
        }
    } );
    
}
```